# Query on bridge table

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I have three tables dealing with books: `Authors`, `Titles` of books written and a bridge table `TitleAuthor`, from from which I am trying to ***find all books (`Titles`) with more than one author***. These are the tables:

```
Authors (Au_Id  PK, Au_fname, Au_lname, ...)

Titles (Title_Id PK, Title, Title_type, ...)

TitleAuthor (Au_Id PK, Title_Id PK, Au_order, ...)
```

In `TitleAuthor`, I am  not sure of what `Au_order` means, but I suspect it is the order in which an author's name is cited in a book with more than one author. `Au_order` is a `TinyInt` data type, btw. These queries are supposed to be introductory, i.e. no fancy joins or subqueries.

This is what I have tried:

1)

```
Select Au_Id from `TitleAuthor` where  Count(Auth_id)>1;
```

But this gives us the author name, not the book name (remember: intro query)

2) Figuring out which books/titles are mentioned more than once in `TitleAuthor`:

```
Select Title_id from Title-Author where Count(Title_Id)>1;
```

This gives me no results for some reason, though no error messages either. I suspect I may need grouping and having, but this is not working either.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Sorry, what was your question?

Comment: Hi @Daniel Hutmacher :Daniel, just wanted a list of the books with more than one author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select Titles.Title_Id, Titles.Title
  from Titles 
  join TitleAuthor 
        on TitleAuthor.Title_Id =  Titles.Title_Id 
 group by Titles.Title_Id, Titles.Title 
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Please note I was looking for a basic query: no joins or subqueries.

Comment: Please note the stated question is find "all books (Titles) with more than one author".  Since that information is in two tables you cannot do it without joins or subqueries

Comment: But look at above reply: it was done within a single table.

Comment: No *it* as in the stated question is not done with a single table.  That query above does  not return Title.  You even capitalized, bolded and italicized  ***Titles***.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Did you get clarification on Title versus Title_Id?  And "titles" is even used in the original.  OP got what he/she was looking for.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter And I don't either.  OP got what he/she was looking for.

Comment: Yes, but each title_id corresponds exactly with one title, so counting number of title_id  with count(title_id)>1 is the same as counting titles with more than one author.

Comment: @MSIS So count is count.   Title_id is not  title.  You literally asked to find "books (Titles)".

Comment: Ah, yes you are right .

Comment: I think Irwin said that a join is necessary, in the bottom of his post. I guess this cannot be done without joins, nor without subqueries.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways. Probably simplest:

```
SELECT Title_id
FROM   TitleAuthor
GROUP  BY Title_id
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

You can `JOIN` to `Titles` to get book details.

Comment: Thanks, re the last comment, please note this is intended to be a basic query,i.e., without joins nor subqueries.